# EE 2.2.0 | Entry page layout is messed up for one specific channel

Tags: toolbar

This is totally weird to me but a new channel I made last week now looks all messed up when you go to make an entry with the channel:

[image]

Basically, the toolbar is destroying the page.  I click show toolbar, and an empty space slides in on the right, where it should be.

What causes this to happen?
How is this fixed?
How is this prevented?

Thanks!

Comment: Earlier versions of EE2 were rubbish with the custom layout and I often had it throw a wobble like that. Try clicking "Reset Layout", this should reset it back to normal and you can customise it again. I'd highly recommend upgrading to the latest EE2 version as there have been lots of security updates since.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Peter.  Reset layout didn't work.  I'll just contact Ellis Labs about it.  I agree...the older EE versions are a bit unstable for sure.  :/

Comment: Afraid the first thing they'll say is you need to upgrade, plus you'll also need a current support contract.